# Remember window monitor for windows in multi-monitor setup (12.04)

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, window-manager

I'm on Unity 3D, in a dual-monitor setup.
I like to keep certain applications on fixed monitors / workspaces.
However, it annoys me needing to move all those windows to the desired monitor / workspace every day.
Is it possible to remember the monitor and workspace for specific windows in Unity 3D? I know KDE's kwin can do it...

Comment: You might be able to do it with the Compiz Config Settings Manager (CCSM): `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` Go to `CCSM > Window Management > Place Windows`

Comment: This 5+ years old unanswered question deals with Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL. OP never replied to comments posted 4+ years ago. VTC as `not reproducible`.